# Trying to get C++ classes to see each other

Tags: c++

I have two class types and one object of each of those types. One class type is Player and I have created a class called Charles of type Player in Player.h. The other class is Karatoise1 of type Karatoise and Karatoise1 is created in Karatoise.h. I need to be able to see some of the integers stored in both Karatoise1 and Charles, both have all the variables inside made public and both Karatoise.cpp includes Player.h and Player.cpp includes Karatoise.h. Both header files also have a header guard I think it's called with the interior of the header file being surrounded by the #ifndef, #define and #endif statements. However, using this setup visual studio tells me there are multiple occurrences of each of both Charles.obj and Karatoise1.obj. If I move around the creation of the classes so that Charles and Karatoise1 are defined in main, Karatoise.cpp and Player.cpp don't accept that they exist. Could you please tell me how I could set up the files so that Karatoise1 and Charles are able to see each other?

Comment: Show some code, please

Comment: You could create a third class called DataContainer which could be a singleton and have your Charles and Karatoise1 with the respective getters.

I think this way the code wold look cleaner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to *define* the classes and *declare* any global variables in headers, so that any source file can access them:

```
// Player.h

// Define a Player class
class Player {
    // blah blah
};

// Declare a Player object
extern Player Charles;
```

Then you need to *define* the object in exactly one source file, so that it just has one definition. This is known as the "One Definition Rule":

```
// Player.cpp
#include "Player.h"

// Define the Player object declared in the header
Player Charles;
```

As you found, with everything in a source file, you can't access it at all from other source files; and with everything in a header, the object was multiply defined by each source file that included the header.

Your next problem will be that each header tries to include the other, which is impossible. The are three possible situations here:

- If the class definition *doesn't* need to mention the other class, and it's only needed within the source file, then everything is fine. Just include the other class header from the source file.
- If the class definition needs to *contain* an object of the other type, then you really will need to include the other header from this header. Of course, it's impossible for both classes to contain the other, so you won't need both headers to include each other.
- If the class definition needs to *mention* the other class (because it has a member that's a reference or pointer to it, or has member functions that take one as a parameter or return type), then you'll need to declare the other class:

Here is an example of the third case

```
// Player.h
class Karatoise;  // Just a declaration, not the full class definition

class Player {
    Karatoise & k_ref;        // OK
    Karatoise * k_ptr;        // OK
    Karatoise do_something(); // OK
    do_something(Karatoise);  // OK

    Karatoise k_obj; // Not OK: needs full class definition
};
```

Answer (score 5):

Do not create objects, or define global variables, on header files. Use `extern` to declare the variable, and define them in cpp files.

Answer (score 0):

You have the error here in you phrase: *Karatoise.cpp includes Player.h and Player.cpp includes Karatoise.h*.

You must not make circular includes.
If you made in `Player.h`:

```
#include Karatoise.h
```

So, you must not make the reverse inclusion. ONLY ONE way.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at friendship in c++, just Google it ;-)
Cheers.

Comment: "just google it" might not be such a good idea, since google uses algorithms to tailor the information to the one who is using that computer. Searches that the OP do and you do can be different. Instead, post some relevant information, examples, actual articles/documention that refer to what you want the OP to do.

Comment: A better answer might briefly explain what friendship is and how it's useful. An even better one wouldn't mention friendship at all, since it has nothing to do with allowing two global objects to access each other's public members.

Comment: Answers should be _standalone_, i.e. be informative _without_ external resources. Sometimes this isn't possible, but here you don't really provide any information and it certainly is possible. Post this as a _comment_ rather than an answer.